# Unity Dependency Injection with Web.Config Not Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, unity-container

I pretty much have the standard Unity set-up

ICardRepository:

```
public interface ICardRepository {
    Task<Card> Get(GetCardRequest request);
}

[DataContract]
public class GetCardRequest {
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public int CardID { get; set; }
}
```

DbCardRepository:

```
public class DbCardRepository : CardCornerDbRepository, ICardRepository {
    public DbCardRepository(IDbConfig config) : base(config) {
    }

    public async Task<Card> Get(GetCardRequest request) {
        try {
            return await ExecuteGetRequestAsync<Card>(request, "p_CardsTest");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    ...
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="System" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
          connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=CardCorner;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>
      <register type="CardCorner.Data.ICardRepository, CardCorner.Data" mapTo="CardCorner.Data.SqlClient.DbCardRepository, CardCorner.Data.SqlClient" />
    </container>
  </unity>
...
```

UnityConfig.cs

```
namespace CardCorner.App_Start
{
public class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);
        return container;
    });

    public static IUnityContainer GetConfiguredContainer()
    {
        return container.Value;
    }
    #endregion

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.LoadConfiguration();

        var config = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["System"];

        container.RegisterInstance<IDbConfig>(new DbConfigProvider(config.ConnectionString, config.ProviderName));
        container.RegisterInstance<IDependancyResolver>(new CardCornerUIDependancyResolver());
    }
}

public class CardCornerUIDependancyResolver : IDependancyResolver {
    public object Resolve(Type type) {
        return UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve(type);
    }

    public T Resolve<T>() {
        return UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<T>();
    }
}

public class DbConfigProvider : IDbConfig {
    private readonly String _connectionString;
    private readonly String _providerName;

    public DbConfigProvider(String connectionString, String providerName) {
        this._connectionString = connectionString;
        this._providerName = providerName;
    }

    public string ConnectionString {
        get {
            return _connectionString;
        }
    }

    public string ProviderName {
        get {
            return _providerName;
        }
    }
}
}
```

UnityMvcActivator is how it comes out the box. That should be everything needed but ask if not. I then try to use it...

HomeController:

```
private ICardRepository cardRepository;

public HomeController(ICardRepository cardRepository) {
        this.cardRepository = cardRepository;
        ...
```

And it throws this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gb5w.png)

I've used Cards as examples but it's much the same. It would appear the 2nd error only happens because of the first. I'm new to Unity and don't get why the mapping is failing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide your full web.config?

Comment: `I'm new to Unity` - Do note that Unity is no longer being maintained. It would probably be better to use an actively supported container instead. Also, XML configuration for DI is considered to be antiquated because of its brittle nature and lack of type safety. If you were configuring in code, you would see compile errors more often than runtime errors and the whole process would go more smoothly.

Comment: How would the full config help? There isn't anything else about Unity there?